# PHP passing variable through href

Tags: php, href

I'm having a little problem with passing a parameter for a query to another page.

I want to make the name of the restaurant a link that would pass the name of the product to process a query on the next page.

```
echo "<p class='p2'><a class='link' href='restaurant.php?name=". $row['name'] ."'><strong>". $row['name'] ."</strong></a>
```

on the restaurant page

```
<?php
require ("db.php");
$name = $_GET['name'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE name =\"$name\"";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);   
?>
```

but nothing is displayed.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: you need to learn about SQL injection, especially when you are a beginner: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: What name are you trying to pass? You may have to use urlencode() to pass the name in the url.

Comment: Stupid question, but... did you `var_dump` or `print_r` your `$row`? I mean, on the restaurant page.

Answer (score 4):

First, a note: you should pass an ID rather than the name, since certain characters aren't great in URLs.

Second, try using `urlencode()` on the name.

```
echo "<p class='p2'><a class='link' href='restaurant.php?name=". urlencode($row['name']) ."'><strong>". $row['name'] ."</strong></a>
```

Comment: @user1354275 you should also make a note of what everyone else is saying about your code being wide open to SQL injection and mysql_* functions being deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it won't display anything, because you don't have any `print` functions (echo, print, var_dump, ...) in your file.

---

Anyways, you probably thought that your query doesn't work. If so, try to `echo` your `$row['name']`. If everything's OK, check if your variable is set, but it probably isn't because you get `null`.

To fix that issue, use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Example:

```
if(!empty($_GET['name'])) $name = $_GET['name'];
else die('Variable name is empty');
```

Try also to add `ini_set('display_errors', true)` to the top of your pages to see if there's any errors.

---

Note that your code is very insecure and vulnerable. Use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before executing queries.

Example:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
```